# How to use boost::crc_optimal with a binary array (array of 0's and 1's)

Tags: c++, boost, binary, crc

I need to use [boost::crc_optimal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/crc/crc.html), which calculates the crc of an array (of chars?).
Example use:

```
// This is "123456789" in ASCII
unsigned char const  data[] = { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39 };
std::size_t const    data_len = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( data[0] );

// The expected CRC for the given data
boost::uint16_t const  expected = 0x29B1;
boost::crc_optimal<16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, 0, false, false>  crc_ccitt2;
crc_ccitt2 = std::for_each( data, data + data_len, crc_ccitt2 );
assert( crc_ccitt2() == expected );
```

The problem is that the data I am working with is a sequence of 0's and 1's. A specific example:

int data [] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

How do I apply the crc_optimal to this sequence?

Should I just convert each 0 to 0x30 and each 1 to 0x31? In that case, how do I get the resulting crc back into binary form?

Thank you.

**Edit**: changed array type from float to int, since that is not the essential part.
It looks like the challenge is that I am working with arrays with lengths that are not a multiple of 8.

Comment: Why float ?! Please use char or other int-like things. And you could convert every 8 data elements to 1 byte...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a byte-wise CRC routine, you need to convert your sequence of bits into a sequence of bytes.  The order of the bits depends on the order of the CRC, which in this case (CCITT-false) is not reflected, so you consider the stream of bits to be most significant bit first.  Then the first eight bits of your sequence becomes `0x85`.  If it were a reflected CRC (e.g. the true CCITT 16-bit CRC), then the first eight bits becomes 0xa1.

If, as in the example shown, the number of bits is not a multiple of eight, then you will need to write your own CRC routine to handle the remaining one to seven bits.  A bit-wise CRC in this case would look like the following for CCITT-false, where `bit` is the float value converted to an integer 0 or 1:

```
crc = ((bit << 15) ^ crc) & 0x8000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021 : crc << 1;
// ... repeat for remaining bits ...
crc &= 0xffff;
```

Had this been the true CCITT 16-bit CRC which has a zero initialization value, you could do something different to handle the extra bits.  In that case, you could append enough zeros to the *front* of the stream to make it a multiple of eight.  Leading zeros with a zero initialization leaves the CRC as zero.  So for the CCITT CRC-16, which is reflected, your 17 bits of data become `0x80`, `0x50`, `0x00`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect answers to be so specific to the crc polynomial. I thought it would be solely about data types and conversion. Would you have anything to add knowing that the specific implementation is: boost::crc_optimal<5, 0x09, 0x09, 0x00, false, false>  crc_epc;?

Comment: Thank you. I hope you're right, but are you sure that the initialization is zero? I thought that was the third parameter, i.e. 0x09 in this case.

Comment: Ah, I misread that.  The initialization is not zero.  You'd need to do your own bit-wise CRC for the bits at the end.

Comment: Thanks, you're right of course, the reason I said hope was that I was expecting you to have misread the 0x09 for 0x00, but was hoping that I was wrong. I am not planning to use the information you gave me blindly.